# Send url with variables through email body in Php

Tags: php, email, variables, url

Trying to build a code to send password reset link through email in response to those who request it.
The email is received on hotmail and gmail, but not on particular mail client I do not know the configuration.
Of course, I tried several arrangements regarding the quotes and doubles-quotes, but it did not give anything.

```html
<?php
$site = "http://www.example.fr";
$from = "info@example.fr";
$nom = "DLSS";
$limite = "_----------=_parties_".md5(uniqid (rand()));
$sujet = "Password Reset";
$text = "Please click on this <a href=\"http://www.example.fr/dlss/login/verif.php?eml=".$eml."&cod=".$cod."\">link</a> to initialize your password.";
$html = "Please click on this <a href=\"http://www.example.fr/dlss/login/verif.php?eml=".$eml."&cod=".$cod."\">link</a> to initialize your password.";

$from = $nom." <".$from.">";

$header  = "From: ".$from."\n";
$header .= "Reply-to: ".$from."\n";
$header .= "Return-Path: ".$from."\n";
$header .= "Organization: ".$nom."\n";
$header .= "X-Sender: <".$site.">\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\n";
$header .= "X-auth-smtp-user: ".$from." \n";
$header .= "X-abuse-contact: ".$from." \n";
$header .= "Date: ".date("D, j M Y G:i:s O")."\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$limite."\"";

$message = "";

$message .= "--".$limite."\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
$message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $text;

$message .= "\n\n--".$limite."\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; ";
$message .= "charset=\"iso-8859-1\"; ";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit;\n\n";
$message .= $html;

$message .= "\n--".$limite."--";
mail($eml, $sujet, $message, $header);
?>
```

In summary, the email is received by this particular mail client when I replace these two lines there :

```html
$text = "Please click on this <a href=\"http://www.example.fr/dlss/login/verif.php?eml=".$eml."&cod=".$cod."\">link</a> to initialize your password.";
$html = "Please click on this <a href=\"http://www.example.fr/dlss/login/verif.php?eml=".$eml."&cod=".$cod."\">link</a> to initialize your password.";
```

With these two lines here :

```html
$text = "Test Email with link. <a href=\"http://www.example.fr\">link</a>";
$html = "Test Email with link. <a href=\"http://www.example.fr\">link</a>";
```

Or with these two lines here :

```html
$text = $eml . " - " . $cod;
$html = $eml . " - " . $cod;
```

Finally, the problem is in the combination of these two parts that are the web address and the two variables, it's been three days that I try to solve this problem but I can not do it alone, it would be really nice to have help, Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's hard to tell what your actual problem is but you seem to be trying to use HTML in the plain text section of the email...

Comment: @Devon beat me to it by a few seconds, but I would add, for the $text variable have the link after the text that says "click here to verify your email address {then put the link here}".  If you put the HTML in there, who knows how an email client set in text only mode might render it.

Comment: The remark of @Devon is right, I have incorrectly transcribed the text version of the message, it's rather :

$text = "Please, to initialize your password, copy and paste on your browser this link : http://www.example.fr/dlss/login/verif.php?eml=".$eml."&cod=".$cod;

Comment: I think I know where the problem came from, I was a little dizzy, I put in the message part (of mail function) what should be in the header part, I tested with the html version only and it works, all my thanks to Devon and Pendo !